# Is it possible to route api calls in different files with angular?

Tags: angularjs, express, routes

I cant get my mind straight about routing of api calls with angularjs and express(ie nodejs). I set up the routing in my server as below:

```
require('./app/routes')(appExpress, passport);
```

I will have three collections in my database. I need to set upp calls to the api for all the collections in my routes file as below:

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
  app.get('/api/compititions', function(req, res) {
        Comps.find(function(err, comps) {
          console.log(comps);
          if (err)
              res.send(err);

          res.json(comps);
      });
  });
  app.get('/api/swimers', function(req, res) {
      // Add code to do something
  });
  app.post('/api/swimers', function(req, res) {
      // Add code to do something
  });
  // all other calls
  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
      // send the rest of the calls to the app
  });
}
```

The problem is that adding calls and code for 15 ish calls will become a very LONG file. I would like to separate these calls to different files or in some way make this file readable. Is that good practice or am I on the wrong path?

Thanks for the help and guidance!